# SuiteCRM Apache Port Error Conflict

Tags: apache, xampp, port, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need help with SuiteCRM 7.4.3 and XAMPP server hosting.

I have a copy of SuiteCRM running on XAMPP Server. It works perfectly until I assign a record to any other User. Whenever I do so the browser hangs and I eventually get the following error:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://localhost/suitecrm1/index.php. It may be down for maintenance
>   or configured incorrectly.

Meanwhile, when the submit button is clicked I see that in the XAMPP dashboard the Apache ports have turned to some different values than 80 or 443 and it happens only when I do the above process of assigning records. [See the image showing the XAMPP dashboard status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp39o.png).

Once I get the error in SuiteCRM the XAMPP dashboard goes to normal as the first status was with port 80/443.

Comment: Make sure that "site_url' is set correctly when changing the port numbers. eg http://localhost:portnumber/suitecrm1

Comment: You can find it in the config.php file